# Turn on and off sound of particular viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ref to viewController which play sound even when a new controller is shown on top of him

Is there a way to control the specific viewController sound? that is mute and un mute it using its ref?

Comment: You will need to provide some specifics about your implementation, by default view controllers don't play sound so we can't provide advice until we know how it works.

Comment: Are you using an `AVPlayer` instance?  Just set the volume of the player to 0 when presenting a new view.

Comment: But he may use the AVPlayer in the new view controller right?

Answer (score 0):

For background modes you need to add a key in Info.plist to indicate that the app wants to run code while in the background.

```
Click the project on the Project Navigator;
Click TheBackgrounder target;
Click on the Capabilities tab;
Scroll down to Background Modes and turn the switch on;
Check Audio and AirPlay.
```

Also you can use this link.May be it will helpful for you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial